# Allow 10k users to unilaterally accept or reject suggested edits

Tags: feature-request, suggested-edits

As a 10k+ user, I can outright edit any post and change tags using the inline editor.  I am all powerful, and you should bow down to my editorial prowess.

*But*, if some noob has suggested an edit, I'm immediately castrated.  I can no longer use the inline tag editor, and if I vote to accept the edit, other ... Excuse me, I've a little sick in my mouth ... *other users must vote to accept the suggested edit as well before it is officially accepted!*

What insanity is this?  Essentially, a *noob* can hobble a 10k god's editing powers!

I'd suggest that 10k users can immediately accept or reject suggested edits.  It's only right and proper.

Comment: Having 10 k reputation has little to do with it. You can edit any post at 2 k, except tag wikis which you can only edit freely at 20 k.

Comment: @Wrzlprmft Having 10k has nothing to do with it *now*.  He's proposing a new privilege in which it *would* have something to do with it.

Comment: Shog [answered this on MSO](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/284901/458741) recently. I suspect his answer will be the same here.

Comment: I think the word that you're looking for is `"unilaterally"`

Comment: @SamIam damnit.

Comment: @ShadowWizard nice call.

Comment: @Won't way too much time spent here has such side effects, yeah.

Answer (score 9):

The suggested edit queue has demonstrated time and time again that rep is not a very good indicator of the quality of the reviewer.  There are *lots* of reviewers with a *lot* of rep doing a constantly poor job reviewing.

Of course, it's not like you need this proposal to solve your problem anyway.  If you want to make edits to a post but can't due to a pending suggested edit, then you should "improve" the edit rather than rejecting or accepting it (you can improve and accept the edit or improve and reject the edit) so that you can fix whatever problems weren't addressed by the pending edit.  It will result in the edit being immediately approved/rejected and your follow-up (or replacement) edit being applied instantly.  This is an option for anyone with edit privileges.

Comment: *rep is not a very good indicator of the quality of the reviewer* Okay, I can believe that.  However, 10k users can edit willy nilly.  How is this any different?  If we must restrict 10k users from approving edits because they may suck, why give them godly edit powers at all?  It's inconsistent.

Comment: @Won't It is indeed an unusual behavior for people without much experience in the system.  People with edit privileges will often be reasonably good editors, when they sit down to actually edit a post themselves, but they won't be good reviewers.  While they wouldn't make a bad edit themselves, they'll approve bad edits that other people propose.  That, and there are also a lot of people that spend time reviewing edits but just don't actually exercise their right to edit posts themselves.

Comment: (my concentration on 10k may end up confusing the matter, unfortunately...  I believe 10k get inline tag edits?  This all comes from being blocked from inline tag edits by a suggested edit)

Comment: @Won't: Because if you try to improve an edit, you are much more likely to have put some thought into what is going on with the post instead of just robo-reviewing.

Comment: @Won't Yes, you'll need to go to the full edit page (by going to improve the edit) in order to make tag edits instead of being able to do inline tag edits.  I don't see a good way around this.

Comment: @Wrzlprmft and if the edit is perfectly fine and does not need improving?  Again, messing with my godlike powers for no good reason!  Away with you!

Comment: @Won't If there is nothing that needs improving then accept the edit and go on with your day.  You were saying here that the main problem was your inability to go and make further edits due to a pending edit; that problem is addressed by improving.  If you don't need to make any further edits, then you don't have that problem.

Comment: Look, you, stop using logic.

Comment: I @Won't do it!  Don't worry, I understand your frustration.  I really wish that these restrictions weren't necessary, but observational evidence seems to demonstrate that they are.